# Apps cannot be installed due to low memory, although plenty is there

Tags: insufficient-memory

A friend of mine has a Samsung Galaxy S2 with 16 GB of internal memory and a 8 GB SD card. I have installed Cyanogen Mode 10.1.3 (Android 4.2.2) a while ago with the Google Mobile Services.

It seems that the internal memory is fragmented into two parts:

[image]

I scrolled down here:

[image]

I do not see how this adds up to him having to more free memory to install new apps. How can this be fixed?

Comment: One of our most frequent questions. May I suggest you first check with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first-aid, and then return here either answering your (solved) question – or [edit] it with some details of what you've found out, tried, and where you're stuck? Thanks!

Comment: The issue seemed to be the accumulation of log files in `/data/log`. I deleted them all and it seems to work again. Thanks for having this helpful tag wiki!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks (+1) for placing the solution along in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were around 1300 files with 1 MB file size each in `/data/log`. I have deleted them using root access and a file manager. Now the apps can be installed again.

Comment: I can't see any /data/log nor /data/app-lib folders, and I also have around 2GB of free space in the internal storage. What can I do? InsuFixer is saying that there are no bad folders.

I've tried everything, I'm one step from resetting everything and reinstalling CM11

Comment: @JonathanPerry Did you use root access to look for these folders?

Comment: Indeed I had root access, but in the end I just factory reset my phone and reinstalled CyanogenMod. Everything is working fine now